# I am installing SiteSupra (CMS) and its dependencies using Php Composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

This is a Symfony Based CMS and require Packages from Git.
I am totally unable figure this out. Please do help, there is a demo site of this cms as well as a Core.
This the repository of Core Base | https://github.com/sitesupra/sitesupra
Hope I Find a Solution

Here's the screenshot of errors I am facing in Composer

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you edited composer.json from sitesupra repo?

Comment: Latest commit in 2015, ignored issues. This CMS looks dead. If there is a choice, pick something else.

Comment: Ye i did tried configuring this out but nothing happened.